# SimpleMembership in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

Just wondering can you add this to any ASP.NET 4.5 project, or does it have to be an MVC one?

I like the idea of being able to use the customisation of SimpleMembership. Also are there any good tutorials or demos on how to add this to a project?

Thanks in advance

Alan

Comment: SO is not a site where you ask for tutorials. However, there are many tutorials for ASP.NET membership, have you a specific question/problem? For example, what means _"customisation"_ in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at below links

SimpleMembership, Membership Providers, Universal Providers and the new ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC 4 templates

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

using-simplemembership-with-asp.net-webpages

http://blog.osbornm.com/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp.net-webpages/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use custom membership provider and custom role provider.

Just implement the `System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider` and `System.Web.Secuiry.RoleProvider` in your class. Then make your classes as default membership provider and role provider in you `web.config` file.

```
<system.web>
.
.
.
<membership defaultProvider="CustomMember">
    <providers>
        <add name="CustomMember" type="CustomMember" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" connectionString="your database connection string"/>
</providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPROLES" cookieTimeout="30" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieProtection="All">
    <providers>
        <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="CustomRoleProvider"/>
    </providers>
</roleManager>
.
.
.
</system.web>
```

Now you can use the Login control in you ASP.Net project and your application will do the rest.